# why Cart::add added product but not stoked using package hardevine/shoppingcart and

Tags: laravel, cart, shopping-cart

I installed the `hardevine/shoppingcart` package using the `composer require hardevine/shoppingcart` command, and I added the line `Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\ShoppingcartServiceProvider::class,` a `providers` and the line `'Cart' => Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart ::class`, has `aliases`,
I created a function in `controller`

**CartController.php:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
     {
         Cart::add($request->id, $request->name, 1, $request->price)
             ->associate('App\Announcement');
         $message = 'Product added to cart successfully.';
         return response()->json(['message' => $message], Response::HTTP_CREATED);
     }
```

to add a product to cart and a route

**routes/api.php**

```
Route::post('cart', 'CartController@store');
```

and function `CountCart`

```
public function CountCart(){
         return Cart::count();
     }
```

and a route for return count cart

**routes/api.php**

```
Route::get('cart/count', 'CartController@count');
```

I tried the functions in `postman`, the `store` function return message '`Product added to cart successfully`' but the `CountCart` function return 0 even I added products to the cart
because I want to use this data in `angular`